# Will \n in jinja2 templates create a problem?

Tags: python, html, jinja2, html-email

I am creating a table using jinja2 template. When I start to write all the html code in a single line, it breaks the table sent via email.

So I am writing

```
table_row = '<tr>\
                    <td>{{dev}}</td>\
                    <td>{{pr_count}}</td>\
                </tr>'
table_row_template = jinja2.Template(table_row)
```

In a big loop, I start appending the data to the the table using the row template.

```
for developer in developer_json:
     dev_count_list = dev_count_list\
                     + table_row_template.render(dev = dev_count[0], pr_count = dev_count[1]) + '\n'
```

Finally when I render using `dev_count_list` inside a base template, everything works fine.

My question - How is `\n` interpreted by jinja2 template. Will it add a new line or just writes `\n` again

Comment: Can't you see the final output code? Can you put a relevant section here?

Comment: To see the final output code, i need to use either print or app.logger which will for sure parse '\n' into a new line while writing to the output stream. I was wondering how would jinja render to the output stream i.e the html.

Also is my assumption correct? Single line html has a limit on the length of the html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this minimal example:

```
t = Template("Hello \n{{ something }}!")
output = t.render(something="World")
print(output)
for b in bytearray(output, 'ascii'):
    print(b, chr(b))
```

This yields the rendered string byte-by-byte:

```
Hello 
World!
72 H
101 e
108 l
108 l
111 o
32  
10 

87 W
111 o
114 r
108 l
100 d
33 !
```

So as you can see, the `\n` character (LF, 10 decimal) is preserved when rendering the output string.